# How to change a panel icon?

Tags: icons, icon-themes

I'm using the elementary-icon-theme on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'd like to change the right-most icon in the top panel (power off/restart menu).

This is how it looks (the monitor icon):

[image]

I'm trying to change it back to default ubuntu one:

[image]

I'm assuming this can be done by just swapping the icon files in the /usr/share/icons but how would I go about it?

Or is there a different way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I essentially did this:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/icons/elementary/devices/22/computer.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/devices/22/computer_backup.svg

sudo cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/actions/22/system-shutdown-panel.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/devices/22/computer.svg
```

It copies the ubuntu power icon and replaces the computer icon from elementary. Your directories might be different.